# Give alternative proof of given theorem (relates to inverses of functions) need to use (b,a)∈ $B\times A.$

Tags: alternative-proof

I have no idea of how to do this.  We need to create an alternative proof using some of the ideas on the bottom, but I'm lost.  Any ideas on how to do this? I'm not sure how to even start the problem...

We are asked to use the following strategy to give an alternative proof of the following Theorem:

Suppose $f: A\rightarrow B, g:B \rightarrow A, g\circ f=i_A$ and $f\circ g=i_B.$ Then, $g=f^{-1}.$

Now we need to create an alternative to the above, using the information below.

Let $(b,a)$ be an arbitrary element of $B\times A.$  Assume $(b,a)\in g$ and prove $(b,a)\in f^{-1}.$ Then assume $(b,a)\in f^{-1}$ and prove $(b,a)\in g.$

Any approaches, information, outline of step, or ANYTHING you can give me will certainly help.  No ideas on how to do this.

Comment: Is there a question?  Assuming there is, what have you tried?

Comment: You should avoid using "inverse function theorem", because it already means something very different from this. I suggest renaming this as "Question on inverse functions" or something like that.

Comment: I suppose you're talking about [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations) and [inverses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_relation) of *relations* (and, in particular, of functions), right? If not, would you care to give definitions?

Comment: yes inverses of functions and believe it uses property of relations.  I know it needs to be one-to-one and onto with g∘f=iA and f∘g=iB, which means g=f−1.  The previous problem we were to apply that 'theorem' but now we need to find an alternative to it, and I have no idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $(b,a)\in g$. This means, by definition, that $g(b)=a$. Since $f\circ g=i_B$, we also have that $f(g(b))=b$. Hence $f(a)=b$, so (again by definition) $(a,b)\in f$. And if $(a,b)\in f$, then $(b,a)\in f^{-1}$.

The other case will be similar. Now use the fact that for two sets $U$ and $V$, $$U\subset V\;\text{and}\;V\subset U\implies U=V$$